# KENDO UI Editable InLine Grid Server bound doesnt display validation messages

Tags: kendo-grid

Using `Razor MVC 4.0`
I have a View with a required field of '`Name`'(as specified in the Model).
I have a `Kendo Grid / EditMode InLine / Server bound Data source` (See Below)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)

```
  .Name("Grid") 

  .Events(e => e.Edit("gridChange")) 

  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Hidden();   //Create a column bound to the "ProductID" property
      columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(120); //Create a column bound to the "ProductName" property
      columns.Bound(p => p.SortValue).Width(80).EditorTemplateName("SortNumericTextBox");   //Create a column bound to the "UnitPrice" property
      columns.Bound(p => p.Active).Width(100);//Create a column bound to the "UnitsInStock" property

      columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(100);
  })
 .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Name ).Editable(true);
            model.Field(p => p.SortValue);
            model.Field(p => p.Active);

        })

     // Configure CRUD -->
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "MonitorType"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "MonitorType"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "MonitorType"))         
        .PageSize(5)

       )
 .Pageable() //Enable paging

 )
```

IN the Controller (HTTP) Edit and Create
Check for the `ModelState.IsValid` (it is false when the Name is blank).
No updates occur.
Returns to the grid.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MonitorType monitortype)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            unitOfWork.MonitorTypeRepository.Insert(monitortype);
            unitOfWork.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        //GridRouteValues() is an extension method which returns the
        //route values defining the grid state - current page, sort expression, filter etc.
        RouteValueDictionary routeValues = this.GridRouteValues();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", routeValues);
    }
```

But - validation message is 'Not' displayed.

How do you display the validation message?

Answer (score -1):

Two things are needed as far as I can see.

First, Assign the error handler event in the `DataSource` (e.g. `.ajax().events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))`).

Second, add the error handler script (this code is available on just about every Kendo UI demo):

```javascript
 function error_handler(e, status) {
    if (e.errors) {
        var message = "The following are errors:\n";
        $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
            if ('errors' in value) {
                $.each(value.errors, function () {
                    message += this + "\n";
                });
            }
        });
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

And lastly, the controller needs to return the `ModelState` as a parameter so the errors can be displayed. Again, look at the grid demo's and you'll see the following in the [MVC controller code](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html):

```javascript
return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
```

Comment: The question pertains to a server-bound grid, in which case the Error event is not available.